# Get index of marked text in Edittext, Android studio kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

[image: This is what I mean with marked text.]

I'm trying to get the start and end index for the marked text in my editText in android studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd`:

```
val startIndex = editText.selectionStart
val endIndex = editText.selectionEnd
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of this class *Selection*

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Selection

Try out method from it